# accessing DOM elements, when button on click to get (name[i].firstChild.nodeValue;),

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to alert just the first nodeValue not all of them, when a button is clicked. Buttons and tables are created dynamically from SQL.

```
function dodb() {
    var name = document.getElementsByName('prezime');
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('bt');

    for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) { 

        if (elements[i].type == 'button') {

            var name1 = name[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            alert ("The " + elements[i].value + " button is click");
            alert(name1);

        }

    }       
}
```

I solved the problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) { 

    // if (elements[i].type == 'button') {

        var oelements = elements[i];
        oelements.onclick = (function(value) {
            var name1 = name[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            return function() {
                alert(value);
                // alert ("The " + elements[i].value + " button is click");
                alert(name1);
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your DOM, how you assign the click handler, and tell us what you want and what does not work with the code you tried.

Comment: function log(img,prezime,ime,Form,ShadeTolerance,MoistureUse,Height20Yfeet,Zone,FlowerColor,FoliageColor,FlowerSeasean,Toxicity,DroughtTolerance,RootDinch,Native, button) {
var btn = document.createElement("tr");var btn1=document.createElement("input");
btn1.setAttribute("name", "bt");
btn1.setAttribute("type", "button");
btn1.setAttribute("value", "add to MyPlants");
btn1.setAttribute("class", "button");
btn1.setAttribute("id", "button");
btn1.setAttribute('onclick','dodb();');
btn.appendChild(btn1);
row.appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("racers").appendChild(row);
}

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12465474/edit) your question, create a http://jsfiddle.net or set up a demo page on your server, but please don't post code in comments.

Comment: I'm trying to alert just the first nodeValue not all of them, when a button is clicked. Buttons and tables are created dynamically from SQL.

cod is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kolaricb/uQYKk/